# Creating contex menu after long click on element of ListActivity

Tags: android

i should create contex menu after long click on element of ListActivity. Here is my code:

```
public class DynamicResult extends ListActivity {

    ArrayList<String> myArr = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> monthAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                myArr.add("....");
                myArr.add("....");
                myArr.add("....");


         monthAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myArr);
         setListAdapter(monthAdapter);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        l.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long id) {
             // HERE
                return true;
            }
        });



    }

}
```

I read some info and created this:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.edit:
                editItem(info.position); 
                return true;
            case R.id.delete:
                deleteItem(info.position);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void editItem(int position) {
    }

    private void deleteItem(int position) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        l.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long id) {
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


     // How from onItemLongClick turn to onCreateContextMenu so that I have a menu?
    //And what to register in registerForContextMenu ();



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            }


        });
```

As planned, I make a long click on the listview element and the context menu opens
How from onItemLongClick turn to onCreateContextMenu so that I have a menu?
And what to register in registerForContextMenu (); ?

Answer (score 0):

> If your activity uses a ListView or GridView and you want each item to
>   provide the same context menu, register all items for a context menu
>   by passing the ListView or GridView to registerForContextMenu().

So you should use like this:

```
monthAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myArr);
setListAdapter(monthAdapter);
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

**public void openContextMenu (View view)**

> Programmatically opens the context menu for a particular view. The
>   view should have been added via
>   registerForContextMenu(android.view.View).

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long id) {
    openContextMenu(l); // l => your listView
}
```